# SSH tunnel daemon for Windows

Tags: ssh, tunnel

For some reason I need to access the Internet through a SSH tunnel connection. The way I do it now is to open Putty and load a tunnel profile.

Since I will need tunneling all the time, is there a program that satisfies the following?

- establish a SSH tunnel
- run in the background; I don't need to interact with the terminal
- lightweight, like Putty
- auto login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`plink`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), made by the `putty` developers.

Answer (score 0):

I use [bitvise tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) along with [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/), they work great.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MyEnTunnel](https://web.archive.org/web/20161029055944/http://nemesis2.qx.net/pages/MyEnTunnel), it uses `plink` and can run as a Windows service.